# MVC project not creating database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

### Situation

- MVC5 EF Code-First project
- Database migrations enabled
- Database in App_Data is not checked in via sourcecontrol
- Connectionstring points to non existing database

### Problem

When someone starts the project the database isn't created according to the connectionstring

### My solution

Edit the webconfig dbcontext connectionstring and modify the `initial catalog` string and now it recreates the the database.

### Gut feeling

This doesn't feel right. Isn't there another whay to do this that doesn't make my skin crawl like my own solution.

Thanx for any ideas.

Comment: Did you call something like `db.Database.Initialize(true)` on `Application_Start` ?

Comment: Tried that too, added it to the global.asax.cs Application_Start() but an `{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}` exception was thrown

Comment: What is your expected connection string look like so that it automatically creates a database? You mentioned about modifying the `initial catalog` as a solution, before that, does it have any `initial catalog` part ?

Comment: Hey Yuliam, indeed it has an `Initial Catalog` part. Editing that gets the database recreated. Has that got something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own DbConfiguration

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDatabaseInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());
    }
}
```

And then Add attribute to your DbContext

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
}
```

For more information about `DbConfiguration` please check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Aiska, I am using code first migrations so I'm using `DbMigrationsConfiguration`